# error C2011: 'Game': 'struct' type redefinition

Tags: c++, классы

```
error C2011: 'Game': 'struct' type redefinition в чем причина?

    //Initializer.cpp

    #include "Game.h"
    #include "time.h"
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        srand((int)time(NULL));
        Game game;
        game.CreateBoard();


        return 0;
    }

    //Game.h

#pragma once
#include "Cell.h"

#define coordXmax 10 //минимально по координате X
#define coordYmax 10 //минимально по координате Y
#define minAmountBomb 10 // минимально бомб

struct Game 
{
    void CreateBoard()
    {

    }
    //void ShowBoard();
};

//Game.cpp

#include "Game.h"
#include "Cell.h"

struct Game
{
    void CreateBoard()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        Cell *board = new Cell[coordXmax * coordYmax]{};
        for (int i = 1; i <= coordYmax; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= coordXmax; ++j)
            {
                Cell cell;
                cell.pos.coordY = i;
                cell.pos.coordX = j;
                cell.countBomb = 0;
                cell.symbol = '#';
                cell.isBoomb = false;
                cell.isOpen = false;
                board[counter++] = cell;
            }
        }
    }
    void ShowBoard()
    {
    }
};

//Position.h

#pragma once
struct Position
{
    int coordX;
    int coordY;
};

//Cell.h

#pragma once
#include "Position.h"
struct Cell
{
    Position pos;
    int countBomb;
    bool isBoomb;
    bool isOpen;
    char symbol;
};

1>------ Build started: Project: Miner_ver_004, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Initializer.cpp
1>  Game.cpp
1>c:\users\mazur\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\miner_ver_004\miner_ver_004\game.cpp(5): error C2011: 'Game': 'struct' type redefinition
1>  c:\users\mazur\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\miner_ver_004\miner_ver_004\game.h(9): note: see declaration of 'Game'
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `game.h` есть структура

```
struct Game 
{
    void CreateBoard()
    {

    }
    //void ShowBoard();
};
```

Но структура с тем же именем у вас есть и в `game.cpp`!

```
struct Game
{
    void CreateBoard()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        Cell *board = new Cell[coordXmax * coordYmax]{};
```

Структуры/классы - это не функции, тут не нужно давать "пустое" объявление, а потом определение.

Если уж хотите вынести реализацию в `.cpp`-файл, то в `game.h` оставьте объявление структуры

```
struct Game 
{
    void CreateBoard();
    void ShowBoard();
};
```

а в `game.cpp` поместите реализацию ее членов.

```
void Game::CreateBoard()
{
    int counter = 0;
    Cell *board = new Cell[coordXmax * coordYmax]{};
    for (int i = 1; i <= coordYmax; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= coordXmax; ++j)
        {
            Cell cell;
            cell.pos.coordY = i;
            cell.pos.coordX = j;
            cell.countBomb = 0;
            cell.symbol = '#';
            cell.isBoomb = false;
            cell.isOpen = false;
            board[counter++] = cell;
        }
    }
}
void Game::ShowBoard()
{
}
```